# Segmentation fault, while dequeuing

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, queue, binary-tree

I'm quite new to DS and I'm trying to implement binary tree level order traversal using a queue. The algorithm is as below.

> 1. Get the root of the tree
> 2. detached_node = root
> 3. while detached_node:
>
>    - print detached_node->data
>    - Enqueue detached_node->left and detached_node->right, if not NULL
>    - detached_node = dequeue()

I'm getting segmentation fault in dequeue(). Here's the gdb core dump.

> ```
> gdb main core
> GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
> This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
> (gdb) r
> Starting program: /home/runner/DryPartialNetbsd/main 
> warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted
> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
> Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00000000004006d3 in dequeue ()
> ```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here and I'm trying to understand.

Below is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct t_node {
    int data;
    struct t_node* left;
    struct t_node* right;
};

struct t_node* create_t_node(int value) {
    struct t_node* node = (struct t_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct t_node));
    node->data = value;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

struct q_node {
    struct t_node* data;
    struct q_node* next;
};

struct q_node* rear = NULL;
struct q_node* front = NULL;

struct q_node* create_q_node(struct t_node* value) {
    struct q_node* node = (struct q_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct q_node));
    node->data = value;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void create_queue(struct t_node* value) {
    struct q_node* node = create_q_node(value);
    front = node;
    rear = node;
}

void enqueue(struct t_node* value) {
    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL) {
        create_queue(value);
    } else {
        struct q_node* node = create_q_node(value);
        rear->next = node;
        front->next = node;
        rear = node;
    }
}

struct t_node* dequeue() {
    if(rear == NULL && front == NULL) 
        return NULL;
    else {
        struct q_node* node = front;
        front = front->next;
        return node->data; 
    }
}

void print_level_order(struct t_node* root) {
    if(root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    struct t_node* detached_node = root;
    while(detached_node != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", detached_node->data);
        if(detached_node->left != NULL) {
            enqueue(detached_node->left);
        }
        if(detached_node->right != NULL) {
            enqueue(detached_node->right);
        }
        detached_node = dequeue();
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct t_node* root = create_t_node(1);
    root->left = create_t_node(2);
    root->right = create_t_node(3);
    root->left->left = create_t_node(4);
    root->left->right = create_t_node(5);
    root->right->left = create_t_node(6);
    root->right->right = create_t_node(7);
    
    print_level_order(root);
}
```

Comment: Try compiling with `-g3` and running with valgrind/gdb. (Hint: See in Line 55)

Comment: Btw, why don't you have any `free()`s?

Comment: So, the output is 1 2 3 5 7. 4 & 6 are missing. Well, that's another bug and doesn't directly relate to the question. Let me take another look and accept your answer. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes because you update *rear* and *front* when you *enqueue* but you only update *front* when you *dequeue*, so in *dequeue* :

> ```
> if(rear == NULL && front == NULL)
> ```

cannot be true if you *enqueue* at least one time before making *rear* non NULL, then after enough *dequeue* you do :

> ```
> front = front->next;
> ```

when *front* is NULL

So modify *dequeue* for instance to be

```
struct t_node* dequeue() {
    if(rear == NULL && front == NULL) 
        return NULL;
    else {
        struct q_node* node = front;
        front = front->next;
        if (front == NULL)
          rear = NULL;

        struct t_node* result = node->data; 
        
        free(node);
        return result;
    }
}
```

note you also need to free memory to not have memory leaks

After correction :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 2 3 5 7 pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```